# javascript window.alert generates error

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to use `window.alert` for debugging purposes, but the `window.alert` itself generates an error message:

```
 Line: 559
 Error: Unable to get value of the property 'alert': object is null or undefined
```

This statement appears at line 560 in http://phillipmfeldman.org/English/hangman.new.html.
Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong will be appreciated.

Comment: Just do `alert()`. Actually no, don't use `alert()` at all for debugging purposes. Use `console.log()`. Although what you have should work (I think, but I'm not going to look into some external source and find the correct line) so you are probably overwriting `window`

Answer (score 2):

On line 578, you're overwriting `window` in the function scope. Use a different variable name.

Comment: Ah!  Good point.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

why not just write..`alert("your stuff");`

```
if (levels_selected == 0) {
alert("You must select at least one level of play!");
console.log("your stuff")
 return;
}
```

Comment: @Phillip M. Feldman:accept the answer you feel is worthy!!!

Answer (score 0):

`window.alert` doesn't exist. You mean `alert()`. As PeeHaa said in the comments, you should use `console.log()` for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

var window= averaging_windows[i_averaging_window];

This redefines window. You should use right local variable names, For debugging, it is better to use console.log, IMHO.